# Having issues installing Ubuntu on Surface Pro

Tags: installation, usb, uefi, surface

Currently I am using Windows 8.1 on a Microsoft Surface Pro. I have managed to disable secure boot and create a bootable USB, but my Surface Pro doesn't recognize the drive and boots into Windows 8.1 anyway. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug the stick in while Windows is running. Go to the **Power** menu and tap **Restart** while holding `Shift`. After rebooting, you should see a menu asking you to choose an option. Tap **Use a device** and it will boot from USB.